# Calculus of Variation: Euler-Lagrange Equation in 1D

Tags: calculus-of-variations, euler-lagrange-equation

I am currently trying to get into calculus of variation for a course of Image processing. In the lecture we learned that a smooth function u[a,b]->R that minimises:
$$\int_a^b F(x,u,u') dx $$
satisfies the Euler-Lagrange equation
$$F_{u}-\frac{d}{dx}F_{u'}=0$$

Okay, now i have an excericse in which the given F(x,u,u') equals
$$ F(x,u,u')=\frac{1}{2}(u-f)^2+\alpha*\lambda^2*\sqrt{1+u_{x}^2/\lambda^2}$$

I then calculated 
$$F_{u}=u-f$$
and
$$F_{ux} = \alpha *\lambda^2*\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+u_x^2/\lambda^2}}*\frac{2u_x}{\lambda^2}=\frac{\alpha*u_x}{\sqrt{1+u_x^2/\lambda^2}}$$

Assuming that this is right I then get with the Euler-Lagrange Formula:

$$0=F_u -\frac{d}{dx}F_{ux}=u-f-\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\alpha*u_x}{\sqrt{1+u_x^2/\lambda^2}})$$

And here my problems start by calculating the second part of this equation:
$$\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{\alpha*u_x}{\sqrt{1+u_x^2/\lambda^2}})=\alpha*\frac{d}{dx}(\frac{u_x}{\sqrt{1+u_x^2/\lambda^2}}) = \alpha*\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(u_x)*\sqrt{1+u_x^2/\lambda^2}-u_x*\frac{d}{dx}(\sqrt{1+u_x^2/\lambda^2})}{1+\frac{u_x^2}{\lambda^2}}$$

Now I feel like i have problem understanding the basics. $u_x$ should be the partial derivative of u with respect to x. If i now take the "normal" derivative will i get the second order partial derivative? So is $\frac{d}{dx}(u_x) = u_{xx}$?
And if i want to calculate $\frac{d}{dx}(\sqrt{1+u_x^2/\lambda^2})$ can I just assume that $u_x^2$is a normal variable or do I have to be carefull because basically $u_x$ is the partial derivative of a function?

Thanks for reading my question.

Max

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just assume $u_x$ is a normal variable and $\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} x} (u_x) = u_{xx}$. Notice that u(x) is a function of one variable.

Comment: Okay that makes sense, if u(x) only is a function of one variable then the partial derivative and the normal derivative are the same (or there isn't even a partial derivative..). 
Is this then also correct: $\frac{d}{dx}(\sqrt(1+u_x^2/\lambda^2)) = \frac{u_x}{\sqrt{1+u_x^2/\lambda^2}*\lambda^2}$ ?
Thank's for your answer.

Comment: Yes they are the same, your formula is nearly correct but you forgot to differentiate  $u_{x}$ on the top of the fraction.

Comment: I thought about differentiating $u_x$ but I'm not really sure how I could justify that.
$\frac{d}{dx}(\sqrt{1+u_x^2/\lambda^2})=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+u_x^2/\lambda^2}}* \frac {d}{dx}(1+u_x^2/\lambda^2) = \frac{1}{2\sqrt{1+u_x^2/\lambda^2}}* \frac{1}{\lambda^2}*\frac {d}{dx}(u_x^2) $
And here I am stuck if I say $u_x$  is derivated just like an ordinary variable i get $\frac {d}{dx}(u_x^2)=2*u_x$ and not $2*u_{xx}$

Comment: remember $\frac{d}{dx} (u_x) = u_{xx}$ so  $\frac{d}{dx} (u_x^2) = 2u_{xx}u_x$ by the product rule.

Comment: Ahh yeah, I totally forgot about that one ... Thank you so much :) :D